# error in implementing the places api dependancy

Tags: android, gradle

implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
error as follows:

```
ERROR: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.1.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

Comment: Use the latest available version for all your gradle dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest dependency version.

Edit your app level build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0'
}
```

Comment: I have tried using 2.4.0 version but still its giving me same error

Comment: Update other dependencies as well.

Comment: Provide your project and app gradle script.